# How to make table dynamic (displaying based on mouse position)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Whenever I normally create an indicator it will display a value dependent on which candle the mouse is positioned at, however when I've created a table it seems to be static only displaying current / last value. How can I make it display dependent on mouse position?

thanks

I'm using the below to fill a cell for example.

```
table.cell(table_id = sizeDisplay, column = 1, row = 1, text = str.tostring(Range), text_color = color.black, bgcolor = color.white)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Tables are static and you can at most update them on the very last bar.
Your options:

- Use the "Data Window" on the right panel: this displays the values of all your plots exactly the way you want it. You hover over a bar and the current values are displayed.
- Try to restrict yourself to some key bars or levels and use labels / lines / bgcolor etc.